# Two dimensional representation of $D_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

I am trying to figure out the $2$-dim representation of $D_5$. Consider the action of $D_5$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by rotation and reflection. Then we can define a $2$-dim representation $\rho:D_5\to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\cos{\frac{2\pi}{5}}&-\sin{\frac{2\pi}{5}}\\\sin{\frac{2\pi}{5}}&\cos{\frac{2\pi}{5}}\end{pmatrix}$, $y\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then I can check the irreducibility by checking $\langle\chi,\chi\rangle=1$. Similarly, we have another $2$-dim irreducible representation by mapping $x$ to the rotation matrix by degree $4\pi/5$. However, my question is that how to check whether it's irreducible without using character theory. Geometrically, in what degree of rotation that $x$ maps to the corresponding $2$-dim representation will be irreducible?

Comment: Take any vector $v$ in the plane, and $Rv$ the rotation of $v$ by $2 \pi / 5$ radians (or in fact, any angle other than $0$ or $\pi$). Then $v$ and $Rv$ are linearly independent, and hence there is no one-dimensional subrepresentation.

Comment: (More generally, a module is simple iff every nonzero element is a cyclic generator.)

Comment: It is not completely clear what is being asked here. Do you mean irreducible as a real or as a complex representation? In fact the answer is yes to both questions - the character theory argument shows that. But if you had been asking about the representations of the cyclic subgroup of order $5$, then that is irreducible over  ${\mathbb R}$ but reducible over ${\mathbb C}$.

Answer (score 1):

If it was reducible, both matrices would have a common eigenvector. Calculate eigenvectors, show that there is no common one.